# Cannot create onmouseover attribute of an element by javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Tried to add  by javascript:

```
 var anc=document.createElement('a')
 anc.onmouseover="aFunc(1)"
 document.body.appendChild(anc)  

 function aFunc(b){ a=b/7 }
```

but cannot give or create any onmouseover attribute of such element
How to do so correctly to solve such problem?

Comment: You can't assign a string to an event handler, use a function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript addEventListener - using to create a mouseover effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318591/javascript-addeventlistener-using-to-create-a-mouseover-effect)

Answer (score 0):

```js
   var anc=document.createElement('a');
   anc.innerHTML="aFunc(1)";
   anc.setAttribute('onmouseover', 'aFunc(1)');
   document.body.appendChild(anc);
   
   function aFunc(a) {
     alert('mouseover ' + a);
   }
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```

Comment: actually, I like this answer.

Answer (score -1):

You need to implement a listener on that object:

```
anc.addEventListener("mouseover", function( event ) {   
  // for example, I am changing the element color to yellow
  event.target.style.color = "yellow";
}, false);
```

More details can be found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event)

Comment: Can you please explain the reason for the downvote?