# Change image when hovering over text with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have a flexbox with a div for an image and another div with text links. It looks something like this:

[Flexbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dS7Dr.png)

I'd like to make it so that when you hover over a text link, the initial image will change to a different image, then change back to the first image once you hover away from the text.

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1Zfj.png)

But I'm not sure how to write the JavaScript to do this. Most of the examples I found online only explain how to change the image when hovering over the image itself. I was wondering if anyone has an example of changing the image when hovering over a different element?

Thanks!

This is just a simplified version of the html and css for my flexbox, I'm not sure how to write or implement the script.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="topics">

    <div class="links">
        <a href="#"><p> Topic 1 </p></a>
        <a href="#"><p> Topic 2 </p></a>
        <a href="#"><p> Topic 3 </p></a>
    </div>
        
    <div class="image"> 
    <img src="#">
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.topics {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

@media (max-width: 560px) {
 div.topics {
    flex-direction: column;
    }
  }

div.links {
  flex: 60%;
}

div.image {
  flex: 40%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen for mouseenter and mouseleave events for the target elements. On mouseenter, attach a new url src; on mouseleave set it back to the default src.

HTML

```
<div class="topics">

<div class="links">
    <a href="#"><p> Topic 1 </p></a>
    <a href="#"><p> Topic 2 </p></a>
    <a href="#"><p> Topic 3 </p></a>
</div>
    
<div class="image"> 
<img id = "my-img" src="">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.topics {
    display: flex;
}

img {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
}
```

JS

```
const imageUrls = [
   "url1" , // default URL
   "url2",
   "url3"
];
const links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
const imageEl = document.getElementById("my-img");
imageEl.setAttribute('src', imageUrls[0]); // Set default image

for(let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", (e) => {
     imageEl.src = imageUrls[i];
  });
  links[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", (e) => {
     imageEl.setAttribute('src', imageUrls[0])
  });
}
```

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I want it to do, thank you! I'd upvote, but it says my reputation is not high enough...

Answer (score 1):

You can do with `justify-content:space-between`

https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_justify-content_space-between

Comment: The html and css already works fine, I'm looking for a javascript solution to changing an image when hovering over text

Comment: Is kind of like that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318591/javascript-addeventlistener-using-to-create-a-mouseover-effect